# HTC M8 Unsatisfied Link Error after 5.0.1 update

Tags: android, adb, htc-android

When trying to push an app to my device using Android studio, I'm getting the below log readout in AS about 80% of the time.  Any clues?

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: htc-htc_one_m8-FA43NWM07298
Uploading file
local path: /Users/Pete/Development/github/myApp/app/build/outputs/apk/myApp_debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.my.app
Installing com.my.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.my.app"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<init>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:65)
at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<clinit>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:60)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getCustomizationReader(Environment.java:523)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.isDynamicSwitchSupported(Environment.java:534)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:222)
at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:142)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:136)
at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:726)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:215)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:106)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted
```

Comment: Does this happen on a plain install to run, or only on an install to debug?

Comment: install to run.  Install to debug actually works like a charm

Comment: I submitted a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158248.

I'm going to try and respond to the questions asked before too long, but anyone else chiming in couldn't hurt. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @codebaum: The issue is now closed with "WrongForum" :-( Any ide aof what is the right forum might be? HTC?

Answer (score 10):

I am encountering the same problem. Wasn't able to solve it. But my terminal is always open and every time it happens I just reinstall with adb to avoid the Android Studio recompile time:

```
.../sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r .../build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

And usually it works. If it fails again, just run this command again (UP ARROW is your friend).

Answer (score 6):

It happens on Lollipop 5.0.2 on the M7 as well. I've found that if you kill the app before deploying, it works out most of the time, and if you have the app open (or running on the background) it will fail a lot, with that error. And it is frustrating because sometimes after that failed, the IDE issues the command for starting the Activity and you see it on your phone so you assume everything went alright, but you're just seeing the last version started.

I've not been able to fix the problem, as I said killing the app from the task manager helps. I've installed CyanogenMod 12 (lollipop as well) on my device as a dual-boot since, and the issue doesn't occur there, so I'm pretty sure it is HTC's fault. I use CM12 now for development since it was costing me too much time :/.

Comment: I have similar problem with Asus, so it's not only HTC problem, but Android problem!

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error on Asus Zenfone 5 (ASUS_T00J) with Android 5.0. For me the solution was to switch off the "Verify Apps over USB" in the "Developer Options".

Comment: Nice, I experiencing this error too. Will give it a try.

Comment: Didn't helped on Asus Zenfone 2 550 :(

Comment: the "Verify apps over USB" pref is grayed out :(

Comment: For my Asus MeMO Pad 7, I had to restart the tablet for this setting to take effect.

Comment: Agreed @BenHutchison, restarting the device helped the setting change reflect.

Answer (score 4):

I worked around this by editing the **Run configuration** for launching the Android app by adding two "Before launch" build step which kills the app. Because the first one often fails I added it twice.

So click the Plus sign under "Before launch", Plus sign again to create a new step (the [Create Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/edit-tool-dialog.html) dialog opens). Fill out the following:

- **Name**: "Kill  my app"
- **Program** `c:\your\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`
- **Paramteres** `shell am force-stop com.your.app`

(Change to the path of your ADB installation and the package name of your app)

Add this step twice before `Make`

*edit*: Turned out this method wasn't bulletproof either, but it reduced the frequence of the error.

Comment: Also this does not work well if you have multiple devices attached, as you'd have to specify the device identifier to adb.

Comment: Heh, funnily enough, force-stopping the app gave me the same "Unsatisfied Link Error". I wonder if THAT'S the issue in the normal build steps when installing an app...

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC M8 too. 
Just do a "Clean" and run your project again ! it works for me. (sometimes you need also to reconnect your device)