# Unable to install apk using adb on device upgraded to Android Lollipop

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

I’ve recently upgraded one of my Android devices to **Android Lollipop (5.0)** and now I can’t debug my application and even install apk on the device using adb. I receive the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.St
ring, java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Lj
ava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
        at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:64)
        at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:354)
        at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:488)
        at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
        at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
        at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
        at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
        at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
```

My device is **Asus FonePad 7 ME175CG or K00Z**

Kernel version

**3.10.20-i386_cpt**

**android@mec9#1**

**Mon Apr 20 13:30:08 CST 2015**

Is there any solution for this problem?

**UPDATED**

first of all thanks to those guys who pay attention to this very specific question, really thanks

for further clarification,

When I received this error, I googled the entire universe for the phrase `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` and gave a try to any solutions that seemed to be applicable, as well as, the solution that suggested by **@Kushal** and others. Most of the questions were (and still are) for `HTC M8` and devices other than ASUS. If you visit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840692/htc-m8-unsatisfied-link-error-after-5-0-1-update), you may see an answer by me which is deleted by SO guards and I admit it that it was not really an answer and I post the answer while I was really disappointed of resolving the issue.

Anyway, what I've done up to now which may be helpful for others are,

1. First, I upgraded my `Android SDK tools` to the latest version **24.2**. After that when I tried `adb install demo.apk`, in some cases it was successful and sometimes not. I killed all running apps on the device (as suggested by some guys) but it sometimes works and sometimes not.
2. Then, I gave a try to other solution, specifically the one that suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840692/htc-m8-unsatisfied-link-error-after-5-0-1-update). In fact, when I try to debug the app using Intellij IDEA, the IDE itself does as the suggested procedure and the result is

[image]

You can see that the IDE itself does as the procedure by @Kushal suggests.

After that, I found several records (referring a few as) [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158248) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170464) and in latter someone has said that

> This was a bug in some HTC devices that was fixed with L-MR1

Therefore I came up with the idea that there may be a fix by ASUS team which you guys know about it and kindly provide me with that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try your application run in `Samsung` or `Google Nexus` device? I think this error will not come on `Samsung` and `Nexus` devices.. if it is confirmed then this is surely error in upgrade binary of `Asus`

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with upgrade binary from Asus because I don't receive that frustrating error message on other devices I have and running Lollipop. The question is how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution though I am not sure if others are willing to use it as it may harm the device and causes it to get useless

In fact, as the answers that the question has received just sound to be copy and paste of other questions’ answers and are not applicable in my case I disappointingly tried to make a radical move and flash my device to downgrade its software to Android 4.2.2 but chancy I decided to flash my device to Android Lollipop again to see if it removes the issue and fluky **it did** (at least in my case)!

**IMPORTANT NOTE!**

**Before following this procedure, consider the fact that your device may get broken and you lose all data you have on your device. So please make a backup copy before you proceed.**

I searched a lot and found methods that are partially described [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=53639853#post53639853) and [here](http://forum.and-roid.ir/thread181162.html) but finally I followed this procedure:

1. Download the correct update file from here ([ASUS support](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20Fonepad%207%20Dual%20SIM%20%28ME175CG%29&p=28&s=7) or [FonePad Support](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/ASUS%20Fonepad%207%20Dual%20SIM%20%28ME175CG%29/HelpDesk_Download/)) according to the type of your device (**ww**, **tw** or others). Mine is ww and downloaded **ASUS Fonepad 7 (ME175CG) Software Image Version: WW_V6.3.7 For WW**.
2. Then change the downloaded file to ASUS_BUNDEL.ZIP
3. Then copy that file in to root internal memory
4. Putting the device into recovery mode (by holding volume up and
   power key down simultaneously)
5. Choose SD Download

The device starts to flash and after finishing it you have a brand new device and the issue is completely removed.

Now I can install apk using adb command and debugging my application as I did before and I have not seen the nasty error anymore.

I'll open this answer to receive others feedback then I mark it as the real answer.

I hope this help others resolve the issue.

Comment: This answer is not safe to perform.. Better consider other solution

Answer (score 3):

Disabling `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration` solved my issue.

Running on Asus Zenfone 2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this issue appears but you can successfully avoid this issue by closing all the running applications on your device.

Also [Unable to test app after upgrading to Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386542/unable-to-test-app-after-upgrading-to-lollipop)

Comment: I have checked that post before but there is still the error message although there is no running app on the device. I can't even install the `apk` using `adb command`.

Comment: Did you try other solutions available there?

Comment: please take a look at the question, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

This error message is due to release binary problem by manufecturer (**Asus** in this case). This error will not appear in **Google Nexus** and **Samsung Galaxy** due to their handling in binary

Solution :

After searching about above problem, the below solution is found on other [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28840692/1994950) question :

1. Using terminal, just reinstall with adb to avoid the Android Studio recompile time:

   $terminal: /sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r

And usually it works. If it fails again, just run this command again

2. If you really want to try it, the process would be:

   1. Close Studio (or try disabling Tools | Android | Enable ADB Integration)
   2. Do the following on a shell:

      ```
       $ adb push /path/to/your/project/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data

       $ adb shell pm install /data/app-debug.apk

       $ (am start command from comment #4/#5)
      ```
   3. Restart IDE (or Re-enable ADB Integration).

This solution is suggested by Google group for alternate fix to above problem [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158248)

Reference Answer : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230530/1994950)

This way you will able to re-install apk and above error will not come

Comment: please take a look at the question, thanks for your attention

Comment: @anonim: thank you for updating.. If my post was useful, pls accept as answer.. this way it will easily solve errors of others..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Asus MemoPad ME70CX and solved by restarting ADB server using command line. Also you may need to kill BlueStacks processes running in background using TaskManager.