# No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Getting the error whenever I install the app on the device.

```
03/24 18:56:08: Launching app
$ adb push /home/itstym/AndroidStudioProjects/hlthee/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/user.com.hlthee
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/user.com.hlthee"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
    at android.os.Environment.getCanonicalPathOrNull(Environment.java:832)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:78)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted 


$ adb shell am start -n "user.com.hlthee/user.com.hlthee.WelcomeActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "user.com.hlthee/user.com.hlthee.WelcomeActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=user.com.hlthee/.WelcomeActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {user.com.hlthee/user.com.hlthee.WelcomeActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

**Solution tried:**

1. Clean the project and rebuild.
2. Invalidate/Restart option.
3. Uninstall the old apk and tried to install again.
4. [HTC M8 Unsatisfied Link Error after 5.0.1 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840692/htc-m8-unsatisfied-link-error-after-5-0-1-update) followed this link answer.
5. [Unable to test app after upgrading to Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386542/unable-to-test-app-after-upgrading-to-lollipop) Followed this links answer too.

Device: Micromax 
Os: 5.0

Comment: what system property you trying to get?

Comment: I don't know. I am just installing the apk in device.  @CaspainCaldion

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem on my Micromax AQ 5001 with Android 5.0. The solution under Android Studio 2.3.1 is **Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration -> uncheck**. You can return this check back if you need to debug your project after successful installation on device.

Comment: In android studio 3.1.3 there is no option in Tools to Disable ADB integration

Comment: I am not able to find how to disable `ADB integration` in **AS 3.x**. So, install apk-file thru cloud, SD-card, file transfer over USB or whatever...

Answer (score 5):

switch off the "Verify Apps over USB" in the "Developer Options".
If it does not work then try **Revoke USB debugging authorizations** in the **Developer Options**

..Answered too late , Hope this may help someone in the future

Comment: Works! Thanks! But only for manual ADB install. I still can't launch debug from Android Studio. Same error.

Comment: @Steve Android studio normally generates the apk file with the name of `app-debug.apk` You need to make sure you don't have a file with a such name on your device. If one exists, delete it and should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

On the Asus Zenfone 2, simply disabling Instant Run fixed this for me.

**Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run** (uncheck the checkbox)

I was able to leave ADB integration enabled.

Comment: This did let me build once. The second time I tried the error was back. What I did this time was to check the box and I succeeded. What?

Comment: Instant run is not a thing anymore in AS 3.5. But still facing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem can be caused if the folder in which your project is located has spaces in its project name. After I changed the project directory to a new folder with no spaces in the path name, everything started working fine.

My Android device was Micromax Canvas Doodle 4 running Lollipop (5.0). I was using Android Studio 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, make sure there is not another apk file with the name of `app-debug.apk` on your device. If exists, just remove it. Since Android Studio deploys a file with that name, it kinda conflicts and prevents app from being launched through Android Studio.